# twisted ssh -X option (x11 forwarding)

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, x11

is it possible to use Twisted with a ssh -X like option, that is, passing the x11 option to the ssh protocol ?

Thanks,
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nope](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/624).

Comment: Really ? impossible to do that with such a powerfull package ?

Comment: Not impossible, it's just not already built-in. It should be relatively easy to implement though.

Comment: If you implement it, please contribute that implementation at that provided ticket.